# refactoring sql schema

Tags: sql

Guys i currently have 2 tables that reference a lookup table. Ive been tasked with modifiying the database to allow the tables to reference more than one value in the lookup table.

My idea is to create a new table that has a new PK and a column that references the lookup table.  The PK of the new table is then dumped into the parent tables thus maintaining referential integrity E.G

Current

```
 Contracts
 =========
 PK Id
 FK lookupId

 Warranties
 ==========
 PK Id
 FK lookupId
```

New

```
 Contracts
 =========
 PK Id
 FK LinkingTableId

 Warranties
 ==========
 PK Id
 FK LinkingTableId

 LinkingTable
 ============
 PK Id
 FK LookupId
```

Is this a good way of handling the multiple references?

Comment: So you have a lookup table to the lookup table now? It looks ok but it can't be fully interpreted without knowing wht the lookup table does.

Comment: @cularis the lookup table is a list of disciplines.  nothing more.  My company now want the user to be able to select a number of disciplines rather than just one and yes i guess it would be a lookup table to another lookup table.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok then it's standard. To change a one-to-one relation to a one-to-many you need something like your linking table so your solution is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your NEW proposed table structure cannot handle multiple references, because each Contract and Warranty row is linked to just one single LinkingTable row.

I see two ways to do this:

1. Add two distinct linking tables, one for each many-to-many relationship:

   ```
   Contracts
   =========
   PK Id
   Other_Contract_Stuff

   ContractLinkingTable
   ====================
   PK ContractId, LookupId
   FK ContractId
   FK LookupId

   Warranties
   ==========
   PK Id
   Other_Warranty_Stuff

   WarrantyLinkingTable
   ====================
   PK WarrantyId, LookupId
   FK WarrantyId
   FK LookupId
   ```
2. Add a single new linking table, to handle both many-to-many relationships:

   ```
   Contracts
   =========
   PK Id
   Other_Contract_Stuff

   Warranties
   ==========
   PK Id
   Other_Warranty_Stuff

   LinkingTable
   ====================
   PK LinkedType, LinkedId, LookupId
      LinkedType ("C" for Contract, "W" for Warranty)
      LinkedId (either a ContractId or a WarrantyId)
   FK LookupId
   ```

The first is the correct and preferrable solution, as the engine can enforce the table foreign keys and data integrity is less at risk. I have seen the latter used in some real world projects. It works, but it is not a good solution... and sooner or later you will have problems with it.

Comment: yes your right.  Looking at back at my solution it is obvious now.  Thanks for pointing that out.  In your first solution are you saying that i need four columns in the linking table?  How do i set the lookupid and the warrantyId to both be primary keys

Comment: You only need 2 columns, but you can and should define 3 constraints: 1 PK and 2 FK. 'ALTER TABLE ContractLinkingTable ADD CONSTRAINT pk_ContractLinkingTable PRIMARY (ContractId,LookupId)'

Answer (score 1):

The approach you suggest is the standard one. The linking table is known as a "Junction" table. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

I would suggest a change to your naming conventions. Also your main data tables don't need the FK any more and the junction table doesn't need its own primary key but rather a compound key on the two foreign keys.

```
 Contracts
 =========
 PK Id
 Other_Stuff

 Warranties
 ==========
 PK Id
 Other_Stuff

 Contract_Warranties
 ============
 FK ContactId
 FK WarrantyId
```

Comment: The linking or junction table should still have a primary key. Perhaps you meant that it doesn't need a surrogate single-column key?

Comment: @Tom H. Thanks. Answer modified accordingly.